# Java method setLanguageTag() accepts invalid region code

Tags: java, locale

The method `setLanguageTag()` of the Class `Locale.Builder` class validates the `Locale`. The acceptable `Locale` is given in the [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) .

The standard states that a valid `Locale` has the region of the regex `[a-zA-Z]{2} | [0-9]{3}`. However the method validates the language `USA` as well ( three characters )

I gave the input Locale as `en-USA` and it was correctly validated. Isn't this a bug in the method as it should have thrown an exception ?

[EDIT] Does this mean that en-USA is a valid locale ? Is it just mistaking USA as some other tag than being region ? And that is the reason why it is validating it.

Comment: The same reference you've added also says "Three-letter language/country codes
The Locale constructors have always specified that the language and the country param be two characters in length, although in practice they have accepted any length. The specification has now been relaxed to allow language codes of two to eight characters and country (region) codes of two to three characters, and in particular, three-letter language codes and three-digit region codes as specified in the IANA Language Subtag Registry **For compatibility, the implementation still does not impose a length constraint**

Comment: It says 3 charachter country code if they are digits. In my case they are alphabets and should not have been allowed, right?

Answer (score 0):

So, I went through the code and found out that there is another category ExtLang in Locale and it accepts 3 characters. 
So it accepts the part after - as ExtLang rather than country.
Thus the Locale "en-USA" gets validated.